# how to return an array from function

Tags: c++, c, client, client-server

I was building RPC based server-client application.

I have a `struct` called `event` that contains:

```
int type_id
long int time
```

I have a function in a server that returns (`event*`):

```
event *
log_1_svc(event *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
    static event*  result;
result = (struct event*)malloc (3 * sizeof (struct event));
while (i <3)
        {
            result[i].type_id = i;
            result[i].time = i;
            i++;
        }
return &result

}
```

What I want is to receive results on the client using this pointer.

Here is the code on the client's site:

```
log_prog_1(char *host,int client_type,int type_id,long int time)
{

event  *result_1;

result_1 = log_1(&log_1_arg, clnt); // this calls the function in server and gurantee that the result is returned an address to pointer

int i =0;
        while (i<3)
        {
            printf ("Type: %d\n",result_1[i].type_id);
            printf ("Time: %ld\n",result_1[i].time);
            [CODE][/CODE]
            i++;
        }

}
```

This code works but it seems that it returns addresses not values (the numbers shown in client terminal is different from ones in server's terminal).

I tried to let the server return `result`:

```
return result;
```

not the address of result (as written previously):

```
return &result;
```

It worked but only the first item printed correctly in client's terminal, the other 2 items are 0's.

Please provide me with a solution and thanks in advance : )

Comment: This code won't compile: you're returning `&result`, which is of type `event **`.  Please post some real code.

Comment: Also, the reason you can't get this to work is because your client and server are (presumably) two separate processes, and will therefore have independent address spaces.  One cannot see the memory of the other.  You will need to look into "shared memory" if you want to transfer raw pointers.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, even with shared memory the memory blocks aren't likely to be at the same address. Rather than a raw pointer you'd want to use an offset into the shared memory block.

Comment: Also, all variable defined in a function are physically destroyed when function returns, so the `event *result_1` variable only occupies memory when the function runs. Once control returns in main, what you get is a pointer to a location of memory whose content is undefined.

Comment: There's also no `i` declared in `log_1_svc`, so I doubt that's your actual code. Your `while` loops could also be better suited as `for` loops. Also, what's the point of the C++ tag?

Comment: @Lubulos: The function is dynamically allocating memory and then (trying to) return a pointer to that.

Comment: @LokiAstari: It's a pointer to a static variable, which in turn is a pointer to dynamically allocated memory.  Nothing goes out of scope here.

Comment: You might like to show us what you are passing to the RPC compiler.

Comment: I think it compiles well even I'm returning and the code is created using SUN RPC and I think that addressing this is done automatically by rpc generator

Comment: I would be very helpfull to see the input you are feeding into `rpcgen`, typically a `.x` file.

Answer (score 0):

A few remarks:

1. There is a blatant memory leak (memory is malloc()'d but never free()'d).
2. i is never initialised in log_1_svc
3. the struct *event result pointer doesn't need to be static
4. log_1_svc returns struct **event, instead of struct *event (as already stated above; by 
   the way, this will compile with a warning there is an implicit pointer cast. Fix your warnings!)

To fix your problem, I would put my bet on 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best soultion is to pass a pointer to memory into the function for the three `struct event` to be populated.

i.e.

```
void log_1_svc(event *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp, struct event *result)
```

This adds an added advantage that the caller could just use the stack and avoid any memory leaks.